# Amazon S3 protection/authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, amazon-s3, token

I have a system that generate some data files. These files contains user data, and I want to store it on Amazon S3 to save my server space and bandwidth, but the file must be protected from unauthorized access. Is there any way to generate a download token for a specific file on amazon S3, or something that allows only users authenticated on my website to download specific files? And invalidate this token after some time or after the download finishes?

Comment: I think you want something like this, [Creating Temporary Security Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/CreatingSessionTokens.html). Post back if you figure it out, I'd be interested as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can implement your own authentication system for Amazon. You need to send Auth token from your backend to users who authenticated by you. The following post from official amazon blog explains clearly.

http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1YVAQ4NZKBWF5/Amazon-Cognito-Announcing-Developer-Authenticated-Identities

Comment: Please consider to add more details, links have a habit of dying.

Answer (score 0):

You can have create the expiration link for the objects that stored on S3 bucket.AWS provide the link expiration services for the objects. When user finished download you can expire the link.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/